# What's up with these words, eh?

Tags: cipher, pattern

hello there = llehht oere

Voldemort's Wrath = dloVrome s'ttarWh

This is weird, right? = sihT si riewr ,dthgi?

Just figure out what is happening to these words. = tsuJgif  eru tuotahw si ppahnineot geht w essdro.

Let me know what you come up with! =  teLk em wontahwuoy moc pu etiw !h

---

*Note: It's not just a simple fixed scramble of the letters.*

*Clarification: Yes it can **technically** be described as such, but I'm looking for something a little more sophisticated than just a fixed scramble.*

Comment: @bobble -- I'm not sure that tag applies as seen by the note and clarification.

Comment: Oh, I thought that there would be some sort of fixed algorithm/procedure that operated on the letters. My bad.

Comment: @bobble -- No worries :):)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be

> splitting the string into 4-character chunks, and reversing each chunk. (The last chunk may end up being smaller than 4 letters.)
>
>  Any instances of two spaces together are trimmed down to 1 by Stack Exchange's formatting, but are still two spaces. (For instance, in the start of the last sentence, where the result string starts with a space itself, in the source it is `=  teL`. Similarly, in the third example, the spaces before and after "figure" are adjacent; in the source they are indeed two spaces, but they are merged into one space by SE.)

Comment: Okay never mind then. I intended something less to do with the placement of the letters (which is what I tried to say with my note), but I guess this is technically correct.

Comment: Will someone explain why my question has 4 downvotes and 0 upvotes? What exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath It appears to be low-effort (a *very* simple reordering that isn't too hard to figure out, other than the formatting issues), and it's unclear what exactly you're looking for if this answer isn't satisfactory.